# Docker non-root secure?

Tags: ubuntu, security, docker

If I set up a Docker container on an Ubuntu server, and then let it run arbitrary/untrusted code like uploaded PHP, Python etc. as a **NON-ROOT** user. Is this totally contained and secure by default(Unable to break out of container to harm other containers/host)?
This assuming that the system is fully updated, and looking away from any zero-day exploits that might be used to elevate.

All the articles on this topic I can find only look at securing containers for running as root(I.e, don't do it).

I understand that this might be a difficult question, but I would really like to get a definite answer before moving on with my app.
Thank you for your time =)

Comment: Secure from what?

Comment: Users breaking out of it to harm other containers/host.

Comment: On Ubuntu, no. [On Fedora or RHEL 7, yes.](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Resource_Management_and_Linux_Containers_Guide/sec-Secure_Containers_with_SELinux.html)

Comment: How so? Is there something I can do on Ubuntu to get the same?

Comment: Nothing as far as I know. Ubuntu is terrible at SELinux. (And it's terrible in so many other ways that I'm continually surprised anyone uses it for anything....)

Comment: From what I understand docker comes with a default AppArmor setup, which is used in Ubuntu.

Comment: True, but it's been plagued with bugs and you have to set it up yourself (if you can figure out how). It is not always-on and working by default, as SELinux on RHEL/Fedora. Not to mention AppArmor isn't very good at what it claims to do; it can trivially be broken with as little as a single hard link.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the info =)
If anyone have any other info on this for Ubuntu I'm still open to that, as Ubuntu is the one I prefer so far. But I will go take a look at RHEL(CentOS?) too =)

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to mention, RHEL and Fedora ship later versions of Docker (currently 1.3.2 and 1.4.0 respectively) than Ubuntu does (currently 1.0.1 in trusty, 1.2.0 in utopic). So ancillary tools that use docker, like fig, that rely on more recent versions of docker have a better chance of working properly.